# cat lines from X to Y of multiple files into one file

Tags: awk, sed, cat, tail, head

I have many huge files in say 3 different folders from which i would like to copy say lines from X to Y of files of the same name and append them into a new file of the same name. 
I tried doing

```
ls seed1/* | while read FILE; do
head -n $Y  | tail -n $X seed1/$FILE seed2/$FILE seed3/$FILE  > combined/$FILE
done
```

This does the job for the first value of $FILE, but this does not return the prompt, and hence I am unable to execute this loop.

For example i have the following files in three different folders, seed1, seed2 and seed3:

```
seed1/foo.dat
seed1/bar.dat
seed1/qax.dat

seed2/foo.dat
seed2/bar.dat
seed2/qax.dat

seed3/foo.dat
seed3/bar.dat
seed3/qax.dat
```

I would like to combine lines 10 to 20 of all files in to a combined folder:

```
combined/foo.dat
combined/bar.dat
combined/qax.dat
```

Each of the files in combined have 30 lines, with 10 each from seed1,seed2 and seed3.

Comment: The prompt disappears because you have not given 'head' a file argument. Using ls to generate FILE and then overwriting FILE looks very fishy as well.

Answer (score 2):

No loop required:

```
awk -v x=10 -v y=20 '
    FNR==1 { out = gensub(/.*\//,"combined/",1,FILENAME) }
    FNR>=x { print > out }
    FNR==y { nextfile }
' seed*/*.dat
```

The above assumes the "combined" directory already exists (empty or not) before awk is called and uses GNU awk for gensub() and nextfile and internal file management. Solutions with other awks are less efficient, require a bit more coding, and require you to manage closing files when too many are going to be open.

Comment: sorry, my question was unclear.. can you edit your answer to accommodate this question (I have edited it)?

Comment: Edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do as we can't tell from a script that DOESN'T do what you want what it is you actually want (clearly since we already tried that and apparently guessed wrong). Include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I guess `for f in seed1/*; do b=${f#seed1/}; awk -v x="$x" -v y="$y" 'FNR >=x; FNR==y{nextfile}' "$f" "seed2/$b" "seed3/$b" >"combined/$b"; done`